# Menu DropDown dentro de post Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, dropdown

Qual seria a melhor forma de colocar um Menu Drop down dentro de um post Wordpress?
 Sendo que os Links deste menu deveram abrir no mesmo post, como vídeo por exemplo... Clica no Menu depois clica na Opção 1 e ele abre o player no mesmo post.

Ou se existe algo diferente que possa ser utilizado.
Eu estou utilizando este plugin de NextPage: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextpage-buttons/

Porém ele não é "flexível", fica sempre em linha reta no topo do post.

Isto é possível?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver esse problema?

Comment: Desisti desta função.